# Haskell X Screenshot Program

Tags: image, haskell, x11

I'm trying to make a program that will get me some data structure that contains the pixels currently on screen. I tried to compile [This example I found on google](https://github.com/xmonad/X11/blob/656104ca552d830562595fa75ff252b54147c16a/examples/ScreenCapture.hs), but ghc complained that *X.getImage* isn't in scope. I checked the library on hackage and it doesn't seem to contain a function by that name. But I did find a function by that name in [The xhb package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xhb).

```
getImage :: Connection -> GetImage -> IO (Receipt GetImageReply)
```

So it takes a Connection and a *GetImage*. I looked up the type and it has a constructor *MkGetImage*

```
MkGetImage
    format_getImage :: ImageFormat
    drawable_getImage :: DRAWABLE
    x_getImage :: Int16
    y_getImage :: Int16
    width_getImage :: Word16
    height_getImage :: Word16
    plane_mask_GetImage :: Word32
```

Most of these look familiar from the man page of *xgetimage*, but I'd never seen *DRAWABLE* before. Looking in the source on hackage, I find

```
newtype DRAWABLE = MkDRAWABLE Xid
```

Now this *MkDRAWABLE* I can't find any info on whatsoever.

I just want to get the pixels on the screen or in some range. It doesn't have to be with a particular library. But if anyone knows how to get this to work that would be great.

Comment: DRAWABLE abstracts X11 drawables (a drawable is almost the same as a window). Use MkDRAWABLE  to wrap a window ID. MkDRAWABLE  is just a newtype constructor, what kind of info you need about it?

Comment: Where is it defined? I think I saw that it was in Graphics.XHB.Shared, but when I try to import it, ghc says it's part of the hidden package `xhb-0.6.2015.8.1'

Comment: Not Graphics.XHB.Gen.Xproto?

Comment: No it isn't in there.

Comment: Hm, looks like it's not exported. But because DRAWABLE is XidLike, it looks like you can use fromXid instead.

Comment: So what I need to do is get the id of the window and call fromXid on it? Any idea how I'd get a window ID with this package?

Comment: Normally if you want a shot of the entire screen you use the root window (`getRoot :: Connection -> WINDOW`). WINDOW is also XidLike so you can `toXid` it. If you need a shot of a specific window you have to identify that window somehow. Normally this involves some simple GUI that allows the user to click on a window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97878/discussion-between-obrazi-and-n-m).